# Java with redistributed JRE: cannot find native dependencies

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I would like to redistribute a jre with my application. I have a problem with using native libraries.

Say I have a jar: application.jar, which has dependencies on two native libraries (dll): a.dll and b.dll. All are in the same directory.

Application.jar contains one class: Test.java
    package com.mytest;

```
public class Test {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("a");
        System.loadLibrary("b");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hooray");
    }
}
```

When executing: `java -jar application.jar` it works just fine.

Then I copy my JRE folder from program files to the folder: `C:\data\jre\`

Now I execute: `c:\data\jre\bin\java.exe -jar application.jar` It fails with the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\data\application\b.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at com.mytest.Test.<clinit>(Test.java:6)
```

When I remove the line where library `b` is loaded, it works just fine. Given that library `a` and `b` are in the same directory, why is the system unable to find `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that `b.dll` was dependend on other libraries. One of these libraries is also placed in the jre bin directory, but not present in `C:\windows\system32\`.

When running with the normal `java` command, it would first look into the system32 folder, where it couldn't find the dll. Then it looked in the folder where `a.dll` and `b.dll` are placed.

When running with the `c:\data\jre\bin\java.exe` command, it would first find the dll in the `c:\data\jre\bin\the.dll`, before looking into the folder where `a.dll` and `b.dll` are placed.

It is not allowed to redistribute the JRE without this dll. Therefore, the workaround was to explicitely load the right dll using `System.load("C:/full/path/to/dll/the.dll")` before loading `b.dll`.

It was a hard search, but the key was to use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and compare both executions.